# How can I define a panel's board shape in relation to a PCB's route tool path in Altium?

Tags: altium, dimensions, panel

I have a round PCB and want to define the panel's board shape with a certain distance from the outermost points (vertical and horizontal tangents) of the route tool paths which are defined in the single PCB.

[image: Panel Dimensioning]

If I want to place a dimension it is neither snapping to the panel area nor to the track in the route tool layer.
If I could make it snap to the rectangle I could at least add the track width of the routing track to my calculations, but I can't even get the red cross to align with the grid as well.

Can this be done like I want or is there no snapping possible to the primitives of an embedded board array?

Version: Altium 23